# Does dereferencing a char* inhibit strict aliasing optimizations?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

Consider the following snippet as an example:

```
*pInt = 0xFFFF;
*pFloat = 5.0;
```

Since they are `int` and `float` pointers, the compiler will assume they don't alias and can exchange them for example.

Now let's assume we spice it up with this:

```
*pInt = 0xFFFF;
*pChar = 'X';
*pFloat = 5.0;
```

Since `char*` is allowed to alias anything, it may point to `*pInt`, so the assignment to `*pInt` cannot be moved beyond the assignment of `*pChar`, because it may legitimately point to `*pInt` and set its first byte to 'X'.
Similarly `pChar` may point to `*pFloat`, assignment to `*pFloat` cannot be moved before the char assignment, because the code may intend to nullify the effects of the previous byte setting by reassigning the `*pFloat` .

Does this mean I can write and read through `char*` to create barriers for rearrangement and other strict aliasing related optimizations?

Comment: This [example](https://godbolt.org/g/k2yEzP) shows that your intuition is right (at least for that implementation). If you are not used to assembly it may not be obvious that for the first function the `*a = 1` has been moved down and merged with `*a = *a + 1`. In the second case, this is prevented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointer aliasing mostly makes sense in scenarios when the compiler can't know if a pointer variable alias another pointer or not. As in the case when you compile a function located in a different translation unit than the caller.

```
void func (char* pChar, float* pFloat)
{
  *pChar = 'X';
  *pFloat = 5.0;
}
```

Here the `pFloat` assignment can indeed not be sequenced before the `pChar` one, because the compiler can't deduct that `pChar` does not point at the same location as `pFloat`.

However, when facing this scenario, the compiler can (and probably will) add a run-time check to see if the addresses could be pointing at overlapping memory or not. If they do, then the code must be sequenced in the given order. If not, then the code may be re-organized and optimized.

Meaning that you would only get memory barrier-like behavior in case the pointers actually do alias/point at overlapping memory. If not, then all bets regarding instruction ordering would be off. So this is probably not a mechanism that you should rely upon.

Comment: you right It only has this effect if you assume that the pointers are not restricted & side effect prone.  https://godbolt.org/g/EVJr8G

Answer (score 3):

I think in general you cannot use that as a sort of sequencing barrier. The reason is that the compiler could do some sort of versionning of your code

```
if (pInt == pChar || pFloat == pChar) {
  // be careful
} else {
  // no aliasing
}
```

Clearly, for the simple case that you are presenting this has no advantages at all, but could be beneficial if your pointers don't change in a large section of the code.

If you would be just using this as means for the "barrier" by using a dummy `pChar` the `else` part would always win. But there the compiler can assume that no aliasing occurs and can always reorder the assignments.

The only data that is otherwise unrelated for which the C standard gives reordering guarantees are atomic objects that are operated with sequential consistency.

Comment: `pChar` does not necessarily need to have the same address as `pInt` for the pointers to alias though. `pChar` could point one or several bytes further down from the address pointed at by `pInt`. Both pointers would alter the same 32 bit chunk of data in some way, yet have different addresses.

Comment: @Lundin, yes, that would make the check in the `if` a bit more complicated, but I don't think that this changes the principal argument. Also comparing pointers that do not point to the same object is undefined, so as C *code* as written here this is not possible. But the compiler could do something equivalent without making things undefined.

Comment: @JensGustedt: The situation is even worse than what you describe.  Both gcc and clang will strip out character-type accesses that write bytes with the values they already hold, even if such accesses had been necessary to erase the Effective Type of the storage in question, and the behavior of the program was defined by the Standard when such accesses were present.

Answer (score 0):

If a program needs to use pointer-based type punning, the only reliable way to ensure it will work with gcc, and probably also with clang, is to use `-fno-strict-aliasing'.  "Modern" compilers will aggressively strip out code which can't change the bits that are held by an object, and then use the resulting lack of such code to "justify" optimizations that would otherwise not be legal.  For example,

```
struct s1 {unsigned short x;};
struct s2 {unsigned short x;};

int test(struct s1 *p1, struct s2 *p2)
{
  if (p1->x)
  {
    p2->x = 12;
    unsigned char *cp = (unsigned char*)p1;
    unsigned char c0=cp[0] ^ 1,c1=cp[1] ^ 2;
    cp[0]=c0 ^ 1; cp[1]=c1 ^ 2;
  }
  return p1->x;
}
```

both clang and gcc will generate code that returns the value that p1 had when the "if" statement was executed.  I see nothing in the Standard that would justify that (if p1==p2, the entire contents of *p2 will be read via character types into discrete objects of type "char", which is defined behavior, and the contents of those discrete objects will be used to overwrite the entire contents of *p1, which is also defined behavior) but both gcc and clang will decide that since the values that are written to cp[0] and cp[1] will match what's already there, it should omit those operations.